# netbeans jar won't work from command line

Tags: netbeans, jar

I created a very simple Hello World program using NetBeans 8.2.
However, when I try to execute the jar file from the command line in Linux using

```
java -jar dist/HelloWorld.jar
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class helloworld.HelloWorld
```

I have tried making the project the main project, as directed elsewhere
on the Web, and the file META-INF/MANIFEST.FM looks correct:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Title: HelloWorld
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
Implementation-Version: 1.0
Permissions: sandbox
Codebase: *
JavaFX-Version: 8.0
Class-Path: 
Created-By: JavaFX Packager
Implementation-Vendor: bob
Main-Class: helloworld.HelloWorld
```

Still, I get the same error.  How can I get this to work?????  I've been
fighting this for several hours.

If you need any more info, let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Does your HelloWorld class have a

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Some code
}
```

?

Comment: Yes, it has a main method.  In fact, HelloWorld.java is the only source file.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since this question is asked, I found this thread when facing the same problem and was trying everything found on web ... Good news is I finally solved it!

You need to download the file "jfxrt.jar" and place it in "/usr/lib/jvm/[java]/jre/lib/ext" (assuming you're using Ubuntu). Then you need to install openjfx using this:

```
sudo apt-get install openjfx
```

Next time you Clean and Build the project in NetBeans, you may find a runnable .jar file in 'dist' directory.